# Geogebra 5 "weak digest" alert from apt

Tags: apt, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I downloaded and installed Geogebra 5 as a deb package. Since then, whenever I do anything with apt, a message is displayed saying:

```
W: http://www.geogebra.net/linux/dists/stable/InRelease: Signature by key 98272894F6478AA4434B41D3C072A32983A736CF uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

I tried uninstalling Geogebra and purging its repository with ppa-purge (but this didn't work since I couldn't find the repository). There was no entry for Geogebra in my installed software list in GNOME (Ubuntu) Software even before I uninstalled.

How should I solve this? I am aware that this is a problem on Geogebra's server's end but since I don't need to use it anymore, I need a way to remove the repository. Thanks!

Comment: Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see if there are line(s) corresponding to Geogebra. If there are, comment out or delete them.

Comment: This should be fixed for now since GeoGebra 5.0.290.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by commenting out the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/geogebra.list`

Comment: You can also just rename or delete the `.list` file.

Comment: It was just a warning anyway so you could have ignored it and hope that the repository maintainer fixes the weak signature.